# Bug na implementação de árvore AVL

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, árvore

Estou tentando implementar uma árvore AVL, porém quando eu chamo a função Insere na main e passo algum valor(int) acontece algo estranho. Na primeira vez o if (da função Insere) é satisfeito, porém na segunda vez que a função é chamada o if não deveria ser satisfeito, porém continua sendo.
OBS: A primeira vez que o if é satisfeito indica que a árvore esta vazia.
A função inserir não é a mesma da Insere, mas ela não é causa do problema pois nem chega a ser executada.

```
void Insere(Tree T,int x){
No F;
F = T->no;
if(F == NULL){
    F = (No) malloc(sizeof(struct no));
    F->left = NULL;
    F->right = NULL;
    F->balanceFactor = 0;
    printf("Primeiro numero inserido\n");
}else 
    inserir(F, x);
}
```

Main:

```
int main(){
Tree T;
T = inicializar();
Insere(T, 10);
Insere(T, 11);
Insere(T, 9);


return 0;
}
```

onde:

```
typedef struct arvore* Tree;
typedef struct no* No;

Tree inicializar(){
Tree T;
T = (Tree) malloc(sizeof(struct arvore));
T->no = NULL;

return T;
}
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar <3.

Comment: Note que na definição de sua função Insere o primeiro parâmetro é do tipo Tree mas quando da recursão você invoca a função com o primeiro parâmetro sendo do tipo No.

Comment: Essa função que é chamada no else é outra função que recebe outros tipos de parâmetros. o problema ta acontecendo no if.

Comment: Uma dica: nomeie suas variáveis corretamente. O que é `T`? o que é `no`? O que é `f`? Você pode até saber porque está escrevendo o código agora. Mas se você parar de mexer e abrir oo código daqui um mês, vai lembrar? Quem ler o código, vai entender? É bom tentar criar este hábito já. Inclusive pode causar muita confusão com erro de digitação e que fica bem difícil notar o erro

Comment: T é um ponteiro do tipo Tree, no é nó. F um ponteiro do tipo nó( mais conhecida como filho).